# config/environments/development.rb command not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I would like run a `gitlab ruby on rails` project.
After  cloning I would like to build up the environment but there is permission problems. `config/environments/development.rb get chmod +x` then I use `config/environments/development.rb` command:

```
config/environments/development.rb
config/environments/development.rb: line     1: Rails.application.configure: command not found
config/environments/development.rb: line 7: config.cache_classes: command not found
config/environments/development.rb: line 10: config.eager_load: command not found
config/environments/development.rb: line 13: config.consider_all_requests_local: command not found
config/environments/development.rb: line 14: config.action_controller.perform_caching: command not found
config/environments/development.rb: line 17: config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors: command not found
config/environments/development.rb: line 20: config.active_support.deprecation: command not found
config/environments/development.rb: line 23: config.active_record.migration_error: command not found
config/environments/development.rb: line 28: config.assets.debug: command not found
config/environments/development.rb: line 32: config.assets.digest: command not found
config/environments/development.rb: line 37: config.assets.raise_runtime_errors: command not found
config/environments/development.rb: line 41: end: command not found
```

And this is the development.rb

```
Rails.application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # In the development environment your application's code is reloaded on
  # every request. This slows down response time but is perfect for development
  # since you don't have to restart the web server when you make code changes.
  config.cache_classes = false

  # Do not eager load code on boot.
  config.eager_load = false

  # Show full error reports and disable caching.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

  # Don't care if the mailer can't send.
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Print deprecation notices to the Rails logger.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log

  # Raise an error on page load if there are pending migrations.
  config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load

  # Debug mode disables concatenation and preprocessing of assets.
  # This option may cause significant delays in view rendering with a large
  # number of complex assets.
  config.assets.debug = true

  # Asset digests allow you to set far-future HTTP expiration dates on all assets,
  # yet still be able to expire them through the digest params.
  config.assets.digest = true

  # Adds additional error checking when serving assets at runtime.
  # Checks for improperly declared sprockets dependencies.
  # Raises helpful error messages.
  config.assets.raise_runtime_errors = true

  # Raises error for missing translations
  # config.action_view.raise_on_missing_translations = true
end
```

Ruby 2.3.0

Rails 4.2.6

bundle install run successfully

The project use 2.3.0 ruby

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you trying to run the `development.rb`. It is only for configuration. Settings specified here will take precedence over those in `config/application.rb`.

When you do a `rails s` i.e run your rails server, the file gets executed. The `environment.rb` requires the `application.rb` before it initializes the rails app.

If you want to just run your rails app then doing a `rails s` should be fine

Answer (score 2):

You don't run the environment file, that is for configuration purposes *only*.

You need to run the web server, which serves GitLab. Read docs about starting the web server, usually it's `bundle exec rails s`, but it would depend on the setup.